# Can't log in to google play during debugging

Tags: java, android, authentication, google-play, achievements

when I'm running my app in debugging with eclipse, it won't log me in, the login circle from gplay just keeps turning?
[image]
so I can't find out why it won't unlock an achievement, when an user gets it.

I have this code:

```
 fbdude = this.getSharedPreferences("fbdudea", 0);
         if((fbdude.getInt("fbdudea", 100000) == 1)){

             Games.Achievements.unlockImmediate(mGoogleApiClient, "achievement_frozen_sparks_dude").setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<UpdateAchievementResult>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResult(UpdateAchievementResult res) {
                        System.out.println(res.getStatus().getStatusCode());

                    }

             });
        }
```

but it only runs when I'm singed in and I only can sign in when I use a version of my app with the publishing keystore...what do I have to do?